# Photoshop - Union of two Smart Objects

Tags: adobe-photoshop, mask, drawing, smartobject

Is there a feature in Photoshop CC18, to automatically create the union of two smart objects?

If I combine these two layers with two blue bars, which are two smart objects for example (ignore the gray background for now), i want the following result:

[image] +
[image] =
[image]

I know, that I can do this with a mask. But as I said, those two bars are smart objects. If I change something, I want the "mask" to automatically update as well and from my knowledge, thats not possible with a simple mask.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another way of phrasing your question would be: "How do I use the transparency of one Smart Object as a mask for another Smart Object?".

That is actually pretty easy to achieve:

- Make sure the two Smart Objects are adjacent in the Layers panel.
- Hold down <kbd>Alt</kbd> and click between the two Smart Objects to create a *Clipping Mask*.
- Double-click the lower Smart Object to enter its *Layer Style*.
- Under *Blending Options*, set *Advanced Blending > Fill Opacity* to *0 %* and untick *Advanced Blending > Blend Clipped Layers as Group*.

[image]

Comment: Thats exactly it. Thank you so much!